# "Execution Timeout Expired" exception while installing Sitecore 10.1

Tags: installation, sql-database, setup

I was trying to install the latest Sitecore 10.1. While installing it, I got the below exception.

```
[-------------- XConnectXP0_InstallWDP : WebDeploy ---------------------------]
[WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
Error Code: ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE
More Information: An error occurred during execution of the database script. The error occurred between the following lines of the script: "10" and "18". The verbose log might have more information about the error. The command started with the following:
"DECLARE @containmentLevel tinyint = CONVERT(tiny"
 Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE.
Error: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Error: The wait operation timed out
Error count: 1.
Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1)
[TIME] 00:04:12
Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1)
```

Any clue what could be the reason for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get it resolved by upgrading my SQL server to the latest 2019 version. I checked the compatibility matrix of Sitecore 10.1 [here](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164) and found that minimum compatible SQL version is 2017.

[image: Database compatibility matrix]

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the "Remote query timeout option" by doing the following. I set mine to 0 for unlimited:

**Using SQL Server Management Studio**

To configure the remote query timeout option:

- In Object Explorer, right-click a server and select Properties.
- Click the Connections node.
- Under Remote server connections, in the Remote query timeout box, type or select a value from 0 through 2,147,483,647 to set the maximum number seconds for SQL Server to wait before timing out.