# [Error]: "DECLARE @containmentLevel tinyint = CONVERT(tiny" [Error]: ALTER DATABASE statement failed

Tags: installation

While Installing Sitecore 10.3, I am getting below error on one of the system on step no. **47** i.e. **XConnectXPO_InstallWDP : WebDeploy**.

[image]

**Error:**

```
An Error occured execution of the database script. The error occurred between the following lines of the script "10" and "18".  
[Error]: "DECLARE @containmentLevel tinyint = CONVERT(tiny"
[Error]: ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
```

Comment: Try this one too if first one not work for you. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27771/execution-timeout-expired-exception-while-installing-sitecore-10-1

Comment: I already checked this...Both errors are different. The link you mentioned is throwing Error: Execution Timeout Expired. And the above which I posted is of [Error]: ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

Comment: To confirm, the solutions in the question Sumit mentioned did not work for you?